# I don't think they can go with us, can't they? / can they?

Tags: grammar

"I don't think they can go with us, can't they? / can they?"
Which one is correct?

Comment: This is more appropriate for ell.stackexchange.com.  The answer is "can" though.

Comment: I take back my earlier comment, this is actually a pretty difficult question to  deconstruct and entirely appropriate here.  I had missed a point earlier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> > I don't think they can go with us, can they?

This is preferable to using "can't they." I think this becomes more evident if you rephrase the sentence:

> > They can't go with us, can they?

The following is partially tangential, but still related. After thinking about it, I've realized that this is a fairly common construction when asking a question with an expected negative response. I think "can they" is a means of adding nuance to the question.

> > Can they go with us?

is a neutral question, whereas:

> > They can't go with us, can they?

conveys a particular emotion that the person asking the question feels. It is understood by the reader that this person expects the answer to be no, but is still slightly hopeful and wishes for an affirmative response.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is "can".

Let's break it down.

> They can, can't they?

Should be familiar.

The opposite to this is:

> They can't, can they?

**So as you can see, the tag question must be negated if the main sentence is negated (they mustn't match).**

This might all be easy so far.

Adding "go" as a lexical verb doesn't change anything because lexical verbs don't really affect grammar, they just sit there in the infinitive minding their own business, so:

> They can't go, can they?

---

Now, if we take the sentence:

> I think they can go, can't they?

and negate it, we get:

> I don't think they can go, can they?

Now, because a different verb is negated than the one that's in the tag question, it might look like the two *can* s must be wrong.  But the important thing is that the tag question agrees with the overall meaning of the sentence, and in this case the meaning is negative, (even though this negation is performed on "do" not "can").

Compare these two though, and it should make it clear why the tag question must still be in the positive here, it doesn't matter how the statement is negated, just that it is.

> I don't think they can go, can they?
>
> I think they can't go, can they?

Comment: I must admit this is a bit weird though.  I don't think they can go, do I?  would make sense easily but your example is harder to justify "grammatically".  It guess it comes down to the fact that the tag question is inflected based on the actual meaning of each part rather than the structure.